# how to use UTF-8 in CGI scripts?

Tags: perl, web, cgi

I am trying to use UTF-8 characters in CGI scripts.

I am using the following header for the CGI script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
#

use utf8;

use open ':std' => ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use CGI '-utf8';

my $q      = CGI->new();
my %params = $q->Vars;

print $q->header( -type => "text/html", -charset => "UTF-8" );
print $q->start_html( -encoding => "UTF-8" );
```

The issue is that whenever I print something to standard output, I get output on the browser that looks like:

```
st\xE1n
```

instead of

```
stán
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Try adding `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";` before your outputs.

Comment: @Mark that didn't help :(

Comment: Anything in yuor error logs?

Comment: mmm, it does say "utf8 "\\xE1" does not map to Unicode at ..."

Comment: @Mark Setchell, `use open ':std' => ':encoding(UTF-8)';` does `binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';` (among other things)

Comment: @ikegami Thank you - I missed that line when I read the code - I was concentrating on the last two!

Answer (score 2):

By using `use CGI '-utf8';`, you indicate that inputs should be encoded using UTF-8.

`utf8 "\xE1" does not map to Unicode` means your input wasn't encoded using UTF-8.

The script doesn't output `stán` because `stán` wasn't provided to the script.

Comment: Not 100% sure. You didn't provide code that produces the problem, and I wasn't able to replicate it.

Comment: Specifically, I don't know what `start_html( -encoding => "UTF-8" )` does, and how it interacts with the fact that you also told Perl the output is to be encoded.

Comment: Just a small note, `-encoding` option for `start_html` adds `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` to the output; by default it will set `iso-8859-1`. I'm not sure but I think it does not affect anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As @ikegami mentioned, your input does not look like UTF-8.

In general, to make your CGI output valid UTF-8, you should do two things:

1. Make sure your browser will understand that you're giving UTF-8 to it. You already did that.
2. Make sure the values of the variables you print are in UTF-8. This is the part that causes much problems. For example, if you get some value from the database, or from CGI parameter, or whatever, you should be sure it's stored *internally* as UTF-8 string. In most cases it means that you should explicitly run `utf8::decode` on that scalar, e.g. if `$stan` is the variable keeping the value you print, just put the following line before printing it:

```
utf8::decode($stan);
```

The `use utf8;` directive in your source means that the script itself is in UTF-8. It means that you don't need to `utf8::decode` the string constants explicitly as they are already UTF-8. But if your `stán` is coming from some external source such as a database, you still need to `utf8::decode` it.

Comment: `utf8::decode($stan);` is wrong. Use `use CGI; my $stan = param('stan'); utf8::decode($stan);` *or* `use CGI -utf8; my $stan = param('stan');`, but it's wrong to decode twice.

Comment: correct; didn't notice that `use CGI -utf8` is used. But I still suppose the problem is caused by missing `utf8::decode`.

Comment: How can you acknowledge the use of `utf8::decode` and say that it's missing at the same time? No, the error is caused by the *presence* of `utf8::decode` when given something other than UTF-8